# How to fetch Digits from a String in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, jsp, extjs

I have a following string in **javascript**:

```
var xyz= "M429,100L504.5,100L504.5,106L580,106L570,98M580,106L570,114";
```

I want to **fetch the numbers and store** it in an array.

I tried following code:

```
var x=xyz.match(/\d+/g);
```

And I got the following output:

```
0: "429"
1: "100"
2: "504"
3: "5"
4: "100"
5: "504"
6: "5"
7: "106"
8: "580"
9: "106"
10: "570"
11: "98"
12: "580"
13: "106"
14: "570"
15: "114"
```

As you can see the **floating point** values such as **504.5** has come up seperately.

How can I fetch this properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply change your regex to this one :

```
var x=xyz.match(/[0-9.]+/g);
```

It will allow you to capture the number and the float as well.

=> http://www.regexr.com/3b46a

Answer (score 2):

You can change your regEx to this to get floating point values also

```
var x = xyz.match(/\d+\.*\d/g)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
var x=xyz.match(/\d+(\.\d+)?/g);
```